# Cloud Function unexpected out of memory with API call

Tags: memory, memory-management, google-cloud-functions, presto

I'm fetching a 84mb table from an external API using a Python Client provided by this company (pytd by Treasuredata). I am running this in a 2GB Cloud Functions environment.
All I do is create a connection, an engine and issue a query. This client uses presto under the hood.

Fetching this 84mb table causes a memory overload of the 2GB environment I've been using for this simple task, as described in the Cloud Function logs. The memory usage graph is below.

I can imagine memory leaks happening, but not sure where to look now. I've assessed the code and that the cloud function does have a return value.

I am simply making a call to fetch a reasonably sized table. What could be the issue ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try the same thing on a VM or on your local environment? did you monitor the memory usage? According to the language and the framework that you use, the data storage can take a lot of space in memory! Maybe a presto side effect!

Comment: If you could provide code that would be helpful but speculation is that you have a loop based memory leak retrieving the table more than once.